# How to post values from multiple drop down menus in the same form

Tags: php

I have a form with a unique identifier for each row. I also have a drop down menu with user names.

basically each row has a task and next to each task a drop down menu with name of the task owner. what I need to do is to be able to POST the users name along with their task id so I can update the owner of the task in one submit.

let say the following is what I have in my form

```
    ID    Title        MENU
    1     Task 1       (please select)
    2     Task 2       (please select)
    3     Task 3       (please select)
make_change
```

if the user selected "Mike" in row 1 then I want to update the database with Mike's ID which is Mike's option value in the drop down menu.

The thing that I am having a difficulty with in trying to link each menu to the correct row id "task id".
this is how my menu code is displayed

```
<select name="user_id[]">
<option value="200">Mike</option>
<option value="205">Jaylen</option>
<option value="220"> Jack</option>
</select>
```

I want to be able to link each menu to the correct task id so when I post the form I can link each menu to the correct row.

How can I include the task id in each menu?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my understanding is that you need to know which `Task ID` is related to which `select`?

Assuming that you create the `select`s in PHP you could simply change

```
<select name="user_id[]">
```

to

```
<select name="user_id[TASK_ID]">
```

where `TASK_ID` is the actual id for the task... (e.g. `1`, `2`, or `3` etc).

Then when you submit to PHP you could loop through your `$_POST[user_id]` with *for example* a `foreach` loop...

```
foreach($_POST['user_id'] as $taskid => $userid){
    //Do something with the information....
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you know the `TASK_ID` you don't need to iterate through the entire post you can simply access the required field using: `$_POST['user_id'][TASK_ID]`

For example...

```
echo $_POST['user_id'][1]; //Echo's the user id for task 1
echo $_POST['user_id'][8]; //Echo's the user id for task 8
```

Comment: How can I access the value if I know the row id? the foreach loop will give me each one top to bottom. but If i know the the id how can I can I access its value?

Comment: If you know `task_id` you can simply use `$_POST['user_id'][task_id]`. So for `task 1` it would be `$_POST['user_id'][1]`

Comment: for some reason it is not working with me. here is what I did $new_call_owner = $_POST['user_id']; then echo $new_call_owner[1]. nothing is being displayed.

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump($_POST['user_id'])`?

Comment: $new_call_owner is a copy of $_POST['user_id'].  if(isset($_POST['user_id'])){
  $new_call_owner = $_POST['user_id'];
 }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37067/discussion-between-steven-and-mike)

Comment: when I var_dump the array i get the following Array
(
    ['1107'] => 214
    ['1108'] => 212
)

Comment: correct and when i do $_POST['user_id']['1107'] it does not work

Comment: Are you able to come into chat? It'd be easier to work things out!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the name for the select tag an array you can make them unique names. This way each row can be uniquely identified. Example:

```
<select name="task1">
    <option value="200">Mike</option>
    <option value="205">Jaylen</option>
    <option value="220"> Jack</option>
</select>

<select name="task2">
    <option value="200">Mike</option>
    <option value="205">Jaylen</option>
    <option value="220"> Jack</option>
</select>
```

This way task1 will map to whatever is selected in the dropdown for task1 and the same for the task2 dropdown.